# Using QueryBuilder to find an array that contains an element

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a database structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "Foo",
    "registrations" : [ 
        101, 
        102
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is create a query that will find all documents that contain a "registrations" array with the value `101` contained within it. I would like to use the [QueryBuilder](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html) if at all possible because I typically find it easier to use.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16815355/531762), I tried to use `elemMatch()` to find it, but that didn't seem to have the desired effect:

```
QueryBuilder.start().put("registrations").elemMatch(new BasicDBObject("_id", 101)).get();
```

However, the stacktrace said that it is trying to cast the `BasicDBObject` to an `Integer` and failing.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
```

So how can I create a query using QueryBuilder that will find all documents that contain a "registrations" array witht he value `101` contained within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more experimenting, I discovered that what I am wanting is the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator, which allows you to check whether or not an array contains particular values. For my specific query, the codeI was looking for was:

```
QueryBuilder.start().put(registrations).in(Arrays.asList(101)).get();
```

This returns the `DBObject` with id `"Foo"`.

If I were looking for more than one registration, I could put them in the list that is the parameter for `in()`.